# Problems in code or my IDE/comp is bugged?

Tags: c, debugging, variables, compiler-construction

I try to refresh some limited knowledge I had in C language today and I stuck with some glitches on VERY simple code that I can not define their nature....

either I am doing a very foolish mistake or something is bugged...

I used the codeblocks v12.11 IDE and set it up to program projects in C (this is the link to dowload the binary: http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries ) I used the ~90MB version of it that comes with the GCC compiler....

I used this IDE (and dev-C++ http://www.bloodshed.net/download.html -which uses a different compiler) on a windows xp and a windows 7 machine...

for 2 pieces of code both (build and compiled individually do not work)

the first code is a very simple one that just adds up 2 values and gives them to an "a" variable...

here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c,f;
    b=10;
    scanf("%d",&c);
    a=b+c;
    printf("%40s, %d",a);

return(0);
}
```

As it is above it dos not work AT ALL!! (**my intention is to display the value of var "a" 40 spaces to the right of the lineoutput**) it return either a null message or windows pop up a fatal error window... (depents on the mood of my pc yesterday only the console returned a null messages today it decides to tell windows that the console window is not responding...)

if I edit the code like this:

```
int main()
{
int a,b,c,f;
b=10;
scanf("%d",&c);
a=b+c;
printf("%40s"); 
printf("%d",a);

return(0);
}
```

it works but infront of any intreusult in displays an ascII character.. like this:

[image]

(strange thing is that when I input the number 7 it does not display a character but instead my pc beeps... also if I input a nonnumeric character it loops endlessly like this:

[image]

if I change the type of the variables to FLOAT everything works fine.. but as you guessed the results are not integers....

[image]

the interesting thing is that if everything is turned to FLOAT but on the scanf properties the input is set to int [scanf("%d",&c);] the program still works and displays results as floats but again with an ascii character infront of them...

the other strange thing is that when I input large numbers like 99999 it displays more than one ascii characters I would expect it just return the result without an ascii char since the ascii char codes are from 1 to 255 or something like that...

so

- **question A**: is my compiler or IDE buggy (was a fresh install)?
- **question B**: if it is what should I do? reinstalling it? same things

  happen...
- **question C**: if its not a software problem (IDE/COMP etc)    then WHY do those ascii characters appear??

PS To project the results all together and take the above print screen frames I used a "while" loop it does not change anything the same results appear when I **build and compile** the code whithout the while loop.. but to be sure I paste the modified code with the "while" command that I used in order to display all the results in one console so that I could printscreen them.

```
int main()
{
int a,b,c,f;
b=10;
while(b=10){
scanf("%d",&c);
a=b+c;
printf("%40s"); 
printf("%d",a);
}        
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) A couple of pointers. First, Don't assume something's wrong with the compiler. They tend to be very well tested, and IDE:s are basically just flashy text editors. Always start with checking the code. Second, try to write questions short and to the point. Third, indent your code. Show an effort in writing a good question and people are more likely show an effort in writing a good answer.

Comment: printf("%40s"); What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 5):

```
printf("%40s, %d",a);
```

You've told printf() to print a string, but haven't given it one.

Try:

```
printf("%40s, %d","",a);
```

As to why random stuff happens when you did that, it's because a string is passed as a pointer, and instead of that pointer you've passed some other data (or if you pass nothing at all, it'll be whatever else happens to be where the argument should have been), which will be interpreted as a pointer, and could result in pretty much anything happening. Random ascii printed, your program crashing, etc.

However if the random pointer happens to point at something which has a zero terminator, it'll print that as a string, and then pad with spaces. When you use two printfs(), this is probably happening - there's just a little bit of random garbage, then the zero terminator. You may even get very lucky and the pointer points directly at a zero, which would look like an empty string. But it is only luck, which you absolutely shouldn't rely on happening. As you've already observed, run it again, or at a different time, or on a different machine, and the behaviour will be different.

Comment: Whell according to C for dummies this command works and prints up the "space" character so it repositions the result 40 spaces to the right -in the book it worked exactly as you see it above-

and if you are right then why is there NO problem when I use two seperate printf's ? the results get printed exactly 40 spaces to the right but it insists on pasting an ascii character to the left of the result..

ALSO if I use float type variables and input the results are correct and placed 40 spaces to the right wiht NO ascii chars...

so probably its not that.. thanks for responding though :)

Comment: Either C for dummies is "bugged", or you're reading it wrong. %40s MUST have a string as part of the argument. If you use gcc and enable warnings, you will get a warning if you "get it wrong" - and it's easily done when it comes to more complex printf statement.

So find where you enable warnings in your IDE, and set it to "warn for all available warnings" (-Wall on the command line)

Comment: @ Mats Petersson: then why it indeed puts the result 40 spaces to the right?? and why it works flawlessly when I set the vars as floats? see the pics on the imageshark links I pasted above

@JasonD.. well strange thing... I thought I tried that.. and yes it worked only this time it displays "," before the result like " ,15" if I input "5" still better than having a different ascii char but I still dont get why it has to display a character next to every result ?

Comment: Luck. I've expanded my answer to try to explain (and it's printing a ',' because you told it to).

Comment: Good expanded explanation by @JasonD, a broken clock is right twice a day.

Comment: @JasonD: thanks a lot for bothering so much but again if your right then why is there no problem when the vars are set as floats? (see the 3rd imageshark link.. which actually doestn appear as a link on my question because I added spaces on it to overcome the 2 links restriction rule for new users by stackoverflow)

Also I would like to add that the ascii characters are not random they correpont to their actuall code.. example if I input 65 the result is (65+10=) 75 and the in outputs A75 (65 is the ascii code for the char "A" if I input 66 it results the char "B" etc)

Comment: Again, luck. It just so happens that the address interpreted as your missing string points at your integer, which in little-endian format will contain an ascii byte, and then a zero. If your number exceeds 255, it'll contain more than one ascii char. If it exceeds 24bits, it'll not contain a zero at all. Same when passing a float - whatever happens is chance. Pseudo-predictable chance, but chance all the same.

Comment: @jasonD so even with the vars set to be floats the same thing happens only that the last byte of the code produced by the compiler before the result is not an ascii byte no matter the iput and that has something to do with the way the compiler interprets floatingpoint values in machine code? humm I think I somehow understood now thanks :)